# Android ListView in Fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

Im trying to create a form in Android in which I have a form with list of items, these items are dynamic so you can add and remove them.

The question is regarding the adding. I allow the user to select from a list of things to add.  Let say are products 
so the user see in the form the products he/she has added but if the user wants to add more clickc a button and gets a screen with the products that can add to his form.

Now Im handling this with Fragments. 
The form is in a fragment where we have all the logic of it, and the "add products" its another fragment but this is a list that have a checkbox on it so the user can select more than one at a time. so Im ding this with an ArrayAdapter and on the getView of the adapter we add the check listener to add or remove the item from the "main list"

This approach is giving me problems, passing the values back and fort from the "form fragment" to the "select products" fragment is not clear.

I wonder if is a better approach have the list on another activity and call startActivityForResult.

I think that way I would have better control over the list even the layout of the list because being a fragment and not a listFragment takes me out some possibilities.

I wanted to ask what would be the best practice or the better way to do this.

Create another activity and use startActivityForResult or try to do it with fragments. 
and if by any chanse you have reference to some code sample that I can use as a how to.

for example gmail you get a big nice clean list where you can select more than one.. I want something like that behavior could that be in a fragment or has to be on a listFragment

Comment: Check out "Communicating with Other Fragments": https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ListFragment you use to list products should propose an interface to send selected items. This interface would be implemented by activity or whatever to receive the list.

Then two ways to handle these item lists :
- Create an activity for results. That way, the activity implements the interface to return the list as result.
- Add the ListFragment to current activity. The fragment which want the item list implement the interface. The current activity gives the interface to the ListFragment.